# How to dynamically change validators at runtime

Tags: formvalidation-plugin

Let's say I have this validation in one field:

```
between: {
    min: 50,
    max: 500, 
    message: 'Please enter correct range'
}
```

I would like to update `min` and `max` at runtime.
How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the `updateOption` method.

See the following code:

```
$('#yourForm')
    // Update min & max options
    .formValidation('updateOption', 'yourInputName', 'between', 'min', 10)
    .formValidation('updateOption', 'yourInputName', 'between', 'max', 90)

    // Update message if you need to
    .formValidation('updateOption', 'yourInputName', 'between', 'message', 'Your new message')

    // You might need to revalidate field
    .formValidation('revalidateField', 'yourInputName');
```

#### # Working example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Arkni/241jzc46/

#### # Refferences:

- `updateOption` docs: http://formvalidation.io/api/#update-option